# New customer registration not working in prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I have recently installed prestashop 1.6.1.5.

In my website [catholicfashion.in](https://catholicfashion.in), customers are not able to register.
No errors are thrown, but after registration, it is simply redirected to login page.

There is no notification in the backend as well.

Please help.

**Edit**

I am using PHP 7 on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Your link for your registration form is false.
In fact your link point to http://catholicfashion.in/login and must point to http://catholicfashion.in/authentification.

[image]

So the controller for registration is not called.

Solution : edit the file in your shop

`[your_shop]/themes/[your_theme]/authentication.tpl`

And replace the form link to {$link->getPageLink('authentication', true)}

Comment: @timeactive are you referring to form action? it is already true in four places. for example <form action="{$link->getPageLink('authentication', true)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" method="post" id="account-creation_form" class="std box">

Comment: @JacobNelson it is for form  "account-creation_form" no for loginform <form action="{$link->getPageLink('authentication', true)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" method="post" id="account-creation_form" class="std box">
  {$HOOK_CREATE_ACCOUNT_TOP}
  <div class="account_creation">
   <h3 class="page-subheading">{l s='Your personal information'}</h3>